# Get the row in JTable that got changed/added or deleted

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a  JTable Whenever something on the JTable changes (a row gets deleted, changed or added) I need to save that in a file.

Is there a Listener to get just the row that gets changed? It's way too complicated to get the whole table, check which entry is different etc.

EDIT: Data is already in table, I need to find out which data got changed, because I use it later...

Comment: Have you tried something to add or delete data from your `JTable` ?

Comment: @Patrick I edited my post. Well, I need to do change the rows in the file, so I need to get them somehow...

Comment: Please show some code, you have your own TableModel or in which way do you add the data to your JTable. Some code would be helpful to find a solution for you.

Answer (score 2):

The simpelest way to accomplish that, would be to implement your own TableModel and override the fire...()-Methods.

Something like this:

```
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class MyTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

    @Override
    public void fireTableCellUpdated(int row, int column) {
        super.fireTableCellUpdated(row, column);
        //call your event
    }

    @Override
    public void fireTableRowsDeleted(int firstRow, int lastRow) {
        super.fireTableRowsDeleted(firstRow, lastRow);
        //call your event
    }

    @Override
    public void fireTableRowsInserted(int firstRow, int lastRow) {
        super.fireTableRowsInserted(firstRow, lastRow);
        //call your event
    }

    @Override
    public void fireTableRowsUpdated(int firstRow, int lastRow) {
        super.fireTableRowsUpdated(firstRow, lastRow);
        //call your event
    }

    @Override
    public void fireTableDataChanged() {
        super.fireTableDataChanged();
        //call your event
    }

    @Override
    public void fireTableStructureChanged() {
        super.fireTableStructureChanged();
        //call your event
    }
}
```

You can Override every Method from the DefaultTableModel, even the ones, who delete the row. so you can save them, before they are deleted.

```
@Override
public void removeRow(int row) {
    //save the row
    super.removeRow(row); // this deletes it
}
```

Comment: theoretically correct answer +1, but OP mentioned FileIO, there is possible issue with EDT/Concurency in Swing